# I have downloaded some files over tor

Tags: anonymity

I have downloaded some files over tor and also open them outside tor.
But they are in .zip format.
Am I still anonymous?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is malware in the .zip file or something that needs to be opened on a non-isolated machine, then no.

If you seriously need to open files that you download while keeping anonymity, just use an isolated computer or virtual network like Qubes-Whonix.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's over. Maybe not. Could be two more weeks.
Nobody knows about your files or if they phoned home.
It is possible that you are not anonymous anymore. The opposite is also possible.